# Cluster directed graph into DAG

Tags: clustering, graphs

I am looking for an algorithm that clusters a directed graph into a set of clusters that form a directed acyclic graph.

For example, given:
nodes: {A, B, C, D}
with edges: {(A,B), (B,A), (A,C), (C,D), (D,C)}

A valid output would be: {{A,B},{C,D})
An invalid output would be: {{A,C},{B,D}} (since the node edges imply a cycle between the clusters)

Thanks for any pointers or suggestions!

Comment: Find strongly connected components (using DFS) and contract each component into a single vertex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component.

Comment: @Valentas (1) How do you then establish the edges between the new vertices? (2) Is what you recommend the same as Kasra's answer below?

Comment: My comment answers the question for a rigid rule which I interpreted from the example (that is, I would only output a set of vertex subsets). If you have a different interpretation, maybe it is best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are exactly looking for is a modification to the [DEDICOM](http://kghost.de/cig_proc/full/paper_31.pdf) Algorithm (page 4). the DEDICOM itself gives you measure for relation between different components of a directed graph. You just need to be a bit creative to use it for converting a graph into DAG. Read the paper and if further help needed just drop me a comment.

Comment: Would you happen to know if that solution has already been coded in either R or Python, for instance?

Comment: I did it myself in Python in half an hour long time ago but unfortunately almost impossible to find it. I just followed the simple algorithm in page 4 of the recommended paper and that is super easy to implement.

Comment: @Kasra Manshaei thanks for this answer. Unfortunately the link to the paper is down. Any chance you can post the citation for the paper?